# Why must my child application have EntityFramework.dll to use Custom Role Provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis

I'm using Forms Authentication to manage access to children applications in IIS.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="App/Login" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/
    web.config
    /Application
        /web.config
    /Sites
        /Child App 1
        /Child App 2
```

I'm also using a custom roles provider:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="<Application Name>.Security.CustomMembershipProvider, <Application Name>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="<Application Name>.Security.CustomRoleProvider, <Application Name>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This works for the most part with two issues:
It only works when the Child App has EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and is some sort of actual application. It fails in some way if Child Application only consists of a .html etc. Why is the custom roles provider not being run *before* the Child application is accessed so I do not need to add EntityFramework?

Additionally, when it fails in some sort of way, it redirects to the login page with no explanation. Is there any way to tell if it failed because the user was not authorised, or if it failed because something else went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed was adding the EntityFramework dlls to the GAC. It appears that the GAC version was incorrect, earlier than 6.0